# how can i have a login with authentication in empty mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

when i was starting my asp mvc4 project.i don't know what's needed for Login,but now i know FormsAuthentication and WebSecurity but i can't use it because empty mvc,i must select internet application when i was start project!
if it's possible i want use something for give a Session to users and they be able to work with [Athourized] ActionResults in my Controller.
here is my login ActionResult and my Commented Autherize Anotation!

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(user users, String username, String password)
    {
        try
        {
        user lUser = db.users.Single(pUser => pUser.username == 
                                     username && pUser.password == password);
        if (lUser.username == username && lUser.password == password)
            {
            //Session["session"] = users;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        return View();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            HttpNotFoundResult result = new HttpNotFoundResult("User Not Found!");
            return result;
        }
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login() 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

for example i want give edit permission to Admin only!

```
    //[Authorize(Users = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(user users)
```

any idea ?